# change top position in a centered image

Tags: css, centering

Hello there I try to move down some pixels an image I just centered, bhut it doesn't seem to happen!

Here is the code I have used so far...

```
.fearless{
       display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

<img src="/toKoritsi/images/fearlessgirl.jpg" alt="fearless Girl"  class="fearless"/>
```

can anybody show me a proper way to move the image a bit closer to the bottom without changing anything else?
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the top edge of an element which is displayed block can be moved down by using `margin-top`

For example:

```
.fearless{
       display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

You can also condense these commands to:

```
.fearless{
       display: block;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  }
```

As an alternative, although I would try the above method first, you may try relative positioning and the top styles:

```
.fearless{
       display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    top : 10px;
  }
```

Comment: I feel stupid...I was sure I tried something like that before I posted the question but I guess I didn't....
thanks!

Comment: You should avoid relative positioning (unless specially needed to), because it won't stretch your site by those pixels, only move the element.